# Compatibility of AMD Radeon ProRender

Tags: eevee-render-engine

Is the AMD Radeon Pro [5300M](https://www.apple.com/macbook-pro-16/specs/) GPU in my 16” MacBook Pro (with a 2.6 GHz 6-core 9th generation Intel i7 processor), compatible with the [AMD Radeon ProRender plug-in](https://www.amd.com/en/technologies/radeon-prorender-blender) for Blender ?

The Blender Developers Blog states “macOS 10.12 or newer is supported” [April 30th, 2019]. While the AMD Radeon website lists MacBook Pro (Mid 2012 or newer) as compatible.

I’ve found several online posts discussing the 8-core i9 processor but I’ve yet to find a discussion about the 6-core i7 processor.

I prefer to err on the side of caution, as you might imagine, I don't want my notoriously expensive shiny new Apple to burst into flames when I hit render.

Thanks, I look forward to your responses.

[PC vs MAC debate free zone ;-)]

Comment: You've tagged your question as "eevee-render-engine". Are you aware that AMD Radeon ProRender is an entirely separate render engine and unrelated to Eevee and Cycles?

Comment: The answer below also just states that you *can* run it, but whether or not it will overheat your device will depend on the cooling of the MacBook, placement of the device and ambient temperature.

Comment: Computers will not melt or catch fire from rendering. The worst thing that can happen is that the computer will slow down or shut itself off.

Comment: Thank you for your replies Robert and susu. It's very reassuring to get a second opinion. In regard to my hashtag, since I'm a newly registered member of StackExchange, I'm not allowed to create new hashtags. It was the closest I could get in my short search for a pithy hashtag. Hopefully as people become familiar with my dry sense of humour, they will catch my subtle hyperbole for effect style of joking. Then again,  perhaps I should just stick to the facts. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR:** Yes, you can use the AMD Radeon Pro 5300M for GPU rendering with the AMD Radeon™ ProRender, if you're using macOS 10.13.3 or later.

---

There are two relevant requirements:

1. The [minimum requirements for running Blender](https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/)
2. The [minimum requirements for AMD Radeon™ ProRender for Blender](https://www.amd.com/en/technologies/radeon-prorender-blender)

---

**Minimum requirements for running Blender (2020-08-07)**

You will need macOS 10.12 or later for starting Blender 2.8x and macOS 10.13 or later for Blender 2.90. Additionally a GPU is needed that is [GCN first generation or later](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_AMD_graphics_processing_units#API_Overview), which is the case for your GPU from the [Radeon Pro 5000M series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_AMD_graphics_processing_units#Radeon_Pro_5000M_series).

---

**Minimum requirements for AMD Radeon™ ProRender for Blender (2020-08-07)**

According to [AMDs website](https://www.amd.com/en/technologies/radeon-prorender-blender) the following requirements have to be met:

> **Blender® 2.80, 2.81, 2.82, and 2.83** (experimental builds not supported) for Microsoft Windows®, macOS®, and Linux®

> **macOS® High Sierra 10.13.3 and up** (10.13.4 required for external GPU support)

> Runs on both GPUs and CPUs. OpenCL™ 1.2 support required for GPUs on Windows® and Linux®. **Metal® 2 support required for GPUs on macOS®**

> - Compatible Apple® Mac® Hardware:
>
>   - MacBook® (Early 2015 or newer), **MacBook Pro® (Mid 2012 or newer)**, MacBook Air® (Mid 2012 or newer), Mac mini® (Late 2012 or newer), iMac® (Late 2012 or newer), iMac Pro™ (Late 2017 or newer), Mac Pro® (Late 2013 or newer) (Models without discrete AMD Radeon™, Radeon™ Pro, or AMD FirePro™ graphics will be limited to CPU rendering with Radeon™ ProRender)

In summary, if you fulfill the following requirements, you're able to GPU render with the AMD Radeon™ ProRender:

- MacBook Pro is from mid 2012 or later
- Operating system is macOS 10.13.3 or later
- Blender version is 2.80 or later, but not 2.9x yet