# Radeon ProRender on Mac: Object has no attribute cycles_visibility

Tags: rendering, osx, radeon-prorender-render-engine

I have downloaded Radeon ProRender 3.0.8 for MacOS.
I am using MacOS 11.1 Big Sur with a AMD Radeon Pro 5300M 4 GB.
This runs on Blender 2.91.0.

After installing the add-on I wanted to select the ProRender as the current render engine.
However, when I do select ProRender, the viewport becomes empty and in the corner the following error message is displayed:

```
ERROR | `Object` object has no attribute `cycles_visiblity`. Please see logs for more details.
```

Under logs I have found the following:

```
Mar  6 21:28:07 MacBook-Pro Blender[2030]: getattrlist failed for /System/Library/Extensions/AppleIntelKBLGraphicsGLDriver.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleIntelKBLGraphicsGLDriver: #2: No such file or directory
Mar  6 21:28:07 MacBook-Pro Blender[2030]: getattrlist failed for /Library/GPUBundles/AMDRadeonX6000GLDriver.bundle/Contents/MacOS/ATIRadeonX6000SCLib.dylib: #2: No such file or directory
Mar  6 21:28:07 MacBook-Pro Blender[2030]: getattrlist failed for /System/Library/Extensions/AMDRadeonX6000GLDriver.bundle/Contents/MacOS/ATIRadeonX6000SCLib.dylib: #2: No such file or directory
Mar  6 21:28:07 MacBook-Pro Blender[2030]: getattrlist failed for /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Resources//GLRendererFloat.bundle/GLRendererFloat: #2: No such file or directory
```

Does this mean, that Radeon ProRender is not installed properly?
Where exactly is the mistake and how to overcome it?

Why does my Radeon ProRender driver not work?

Note: I have found a [post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/190158/compatibility-of-amd-radeon-prorender) that says, that Radeon ProRender can be used for my device.

This [post](https://community.amd.com/t5/blender-discussions/cannot-get-pro-render-to-work-in-blender-2-82a/td-p/270706) claims, that I have to switch off cycles. However, it is not even displayed as an option for me.

Comment: Me too. Me too. - 2.93 / 3.0a

Comment: cycles is an addon you can disable

Answer (score 1):

After updating blender on mac i9 Vega 64 - from 2.93 - 3.0, when using Pro Render engine same issue `Object` object has no attribute `cycles_visiblity`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).